# cephadm: Not able to add nodes to ceph cluster (Error EINVAL: Failed to connect to host)

Tags: ceph, cephfs

I followed the following steps from https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephadm/install/ to setup a ceph cluster on Centos 8.1

```
curl --silent --remote-name --location https://github.com/ceph/ceph/raw/octopus/src/cephadm/cephadm
chmod +x cephadm
./cephadm add-repo --release octopus
./cephadm install
```

After the above command I found out that ceph requires either docker or podman to run. So I installed the community version of docker from https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/ and continued the steps below.

```
./cephadm install
mkdir -p /etc/ceph
cephadm bootstrap --mon-ip *ip_of_the_current_machine (host1)*
cephadm install ceph-common
ssh-copy-id -f -i /etc/ceph/ceph.pub root@host2*
ceph orch host add host2
```

The above command fails with the error

```
[root@host1 home]# ceph orch host add host2
INFO:cephadm:Inferring fsid 12345678-2345-6789-1011-000129110013
INFO:cephadm:Inferring config /var/lib/ceph/12345678-2345-6789-1011-000129110013/mon.host1/config
INFO:cephadm:Using recent ceph image ceph/ceph:v15
Error EINVAL: Failed to connect to host2 (host2).
Check that the host is reachable and accepts connections using the cephadm SSH key
 
you may want to run:
> ceph cephadm get-ssh-config > ssh_config
> ceph config-key get mgr/cephadm/ssh_identity_key > key
> ssh -F ssh_config -i key root@host2
```

I am able to login to host2 using the above steps.
Could someone please tell if I am doing something wrong. How do I solve this problem.

Comment: Hello everyone, I would like to point out that any comments are welcome. If you plan to downvote this question, please make sure to add a comment so that helps me put this question in a better way.

Comment: It's unclear to me where your setup could be wrong. I just deployed a cluster with `cephadm bootstrap` and added a second node successfully. Did you install cephadm on the second node, too? Did you check if your ssh connection worked passwordless? I should mention that I installed cephadm directly from the repository (openSUSE Leap 15.2), not with the github script. But it worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: Also does the name resolution work? At least having both hosts in `/etc/hosts` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after days of debugging I figured out that python3 was missing on the node I wanted to add. All I had to do was check the last few logs using the command.

```
ceph log last cephadm
```

This gave the following log messages.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/cephadm/module.py", line 1036, in _remote_connection
    raise execnet.gateway_bootstrap.HostNotFound(msg)
execnet.gateway_bootstrap.HostNotFound: Can't communicate with remote host `host2`, possibly because python3 is not installed there: cannot send (already closed?)
 
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/_interface.py", line 295, in _finalize
    next_result = self._on_complete(self._value)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/cephadm/module.py", line 103, in <lambda>
    return CephadmCompletion(on_complete=lambda _: f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/cephadm/module.py", line 1201, in add_host
    return self._add_host(spec)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/cephadm/module.py", line 1187, in _add_host
    error_ok=True, no_fsid=True)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/cephadm/module.py", line 1104, in _run_cephadm
    with self._remote_connection(host, addr) as tpl:
  File "/lib64/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/cephadm/module.py", line 1055, in _remote_connection
    raise OrchestratorError(msg) from e
orchestrator._interface.OrchestratorError: Failed to connect to host2 (host2).
Check that the host is reachable and accepts connections using the cephadm SSH key
```

Next to add the node I ran.

```
ceph orch host add host2 ip_address
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with the same issue but my top error message was

```
2021-01-13T15:21:13.071913+0000 mgr.ha1.qzzjzw (mgr.18492) 167366 : cephadm [ERR] _Promise failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/execnet/gateway_bootstrap.py", line 48, in bootstrap_exec
    s = io.read(1)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/execnet/gateway_base.py", line 402, in read
    raise EOFError("expected %d bytes, got %d" % (numbytes, len(buf)))
EOFError: expected 1 bytes, got 0
```

and workaround helps me as well

```
ceph orch host add host2 ip_address
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue as Oleg using cephadm on debian 10.

The workaround was to add the IP address.

```
sudo ./cephadm shell
ceph orch host add host2 ip_address
Added host 'host2'
```

Comment: You may just run without 'cephadm shell', i.e.: 

$ sudo ceph orch host add host2 ip_address